# How to fire method only once when using panright with Hammer.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, dom-events, hammer.js

I am running into issues with getting [Hammer.js](http://hammerjs.github.io/getting-started/) (with the jQuery plugin) to function properly when using `swiperight`. Therefore, I need to use `panright`.

When panning to the right, my event fires many, many times.

How can this be updated so it only runs once? (then again when the user swipes to the right or left on another slide)

```
$('.slide').hammer().on('panright', doSomething);
```

Comment: FWIW, I found I was getting multiple Hammer events firing because I'd inadvertently installed multiple handlers for the same event. Worth checking that your control flow's not doing the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you should capture a panend event. For example:

```
var myElement = document.getElementById('myID');
var mc = new Hammer.Manager(myElement);
mc.add(new Hammer.Pan({direction:Hammer.DIRECTION_HORIZONTAL, threshold:80, pointers: 0}));
mc.on("panend", function(ev) {
  if(ev.direction == Hammer.DIRECTION_RIGHT) 
  {
    //do what you want here
  }
});
```

Comment: doesn't pick up anything with panend

Comment: wow.. that worked like a charm.. Perfect... Saved a lot of time !!!"

Answer (score 2):

You can filter the event by **isFinal** property:

```js
var mc = new Hammer($('.screen'));
mc.on("swipeleft", moveHandler);
mc.on("swiperight", moveHandler);

function moveHandler(event){
  if(event.isFinal){
  // do something on the last animation frame
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are other events called 'swipeleft' and 'swiperight'. This will respond to 1 swipe event instead of pan's multiple fired events.

```
var mc = new Hammer($('.screen'));
mc.on("swipeleft", moveHandler);
mc.on("swiperight", moveHandler);

function moveHandler(event){
    // do something
}
```

[Documentation](http://hammerjs.github.io/recognizer-swipe/)

Comment: Link only answers are routinely reviewed and deleted. You should copy the relevant code examples here in case the link goes bad at some point.